# TeamSpeak 3 get information to website

Tags: php, teamspeak

I need a help with teamspeak server information.

**Example:**

- Server name: Teamspeak server
- Online: 35/100

So, How to get teamspeak server information, how much players online, hostname and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Planet Teamspeak Framework.
https://github.com/planetteamspeak/ts3phpframework

```
<?php

include "libraries/TeamSpeak3/TeamSpeak3.php"; // include ts3api library 
 
    try
    {
      // connect to server, authenticate and grab info
      $ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://serveradmin:password@hostname:10011/?server_port=9987");
      
      // show server as online
      echo "Server Status: Online<br />\n";
      echo "Server IP: " . $ts3->getAdapterHost() . ":" . $ts3->virtualserver_port . "<br />\n";
      echo "Server Uptime: " . TeamSpeak3_Helper_Convert::seconds($ts3->virtualserver_uptime) . "<br />\n";
      echo "Server Version: " . TeamSpeak3_Helper_Convert::version($ts3->virtualserver_version) . "<br />\n";
      echo "Current Clients: " . $ts3->virtualserver_clientsonline . " / " . $ts3->virtualserver_maxclients . "<br />\n";
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
      // grab errors and show server as offline
      echo "Server Status: Offline<br />\n";
    }
?>
```

This is simple showcase of this framework, but you can do much more with it.